# How to store date+time as UTC with SQLAlchemy/PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I store a datetime with SQLAlchemy? Should I even be using DateTime as the column type?

At the moment my date + time is in ISO format from the client (Javascript):

```
2015-04-13 01:00:00
```

How would I store this as UTC on the server? Would it be better to have a unix timestamp from the Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides Time based on user / client timezone. Thus the time that you get in Javascript will vary as per the user location.

You will have to get the time and client timezone : refer [get client timezone and convert it to gmt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)
Then change the time as per UTC and pass it to server and save it in database

Else refer: [UTC date and time](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)  to get the UTC date / time objects of the client time , form its ISO format and pass it to server n save in DB.

Saving date and time in UTC helps converting time based on user timezone when ever required.